# Type constructor escapes its scope between functions in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

```
match node with
| Element (description) ->
  otherFuncThatHandles description
```

Description is a polymorphic type, it's parameterized by three other types.

```
type ('a, 'b, 'c) elementDescription
```

The type constructor of description would escape its scope when I pass `description` to `otherFuncThatHandles`. I kind of get the why of the error, but I don't know how to solve it.
Is there a possibility to somehow pass those type constructors to `otherFuncThatHandles` so they are in the scope of `otherFuncThatHandles`?
I could make an extra record type to pass description? I think polymorphism is allowed inside a record. Is there another way?

Comment: You need to provide more details. In particular the complete function you are currently defining and the definition of `elementDescription`.

Comment: We always welcome small and self contained code examples which can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem (nor any type error) if the `otherFuncThatHandles` is indeed polymorphic, for example like:

```
# let otherFuncThatHandles x = x ;;
val otherFuncThatHandles : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
# type ('a, 'b, 'c) elementDescription = Description of ('a * 'b * 'c) ;;
type ('a, 'b, 'c) elementDescription = Description of ('a * 'b * 'c)
# type ('a, 'b, 'c) element = Element of ('a, 'b, 'c) elementDescription ;;
type ('a, 'b, 'c) element = Element of ('a, 'b, 'c) elementDescription
# let f node =
    match node with
    | Element description ->
      otherFuncThatHandles description ;;
val f : ('a, 'b, 'c) element -> ('a, 'b, 'c) elementDescription = <fun>
# f (Element(Description(42, "hello", true))) ;;
- : (int, string, bool) elementDescription = Description (42, "hello", true)
```

Perhaps you have another problem that causes the type error.